# \hfill \break does not work

Tags: boxes

I have following text chunk:

```
\colorbox{gray}{[862401.693536] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off\hfill \break
[862401.693548] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08\hfill \break
[862401.700884]  sdb: sdb1\hfill \break
[862401.705538] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present\hfill \break
[862401.705551] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through\hfill \break
[862401.705562] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk}
```

The output is visible in attached screenshot. Why `\hfill` and `\break` combo does not work?[image]

Comment: Can you extend that *chunk* into compilable code?

Comment: @Johannes_B, sorry, but I do not understand you. If you mean if I can compile code, then the answer is yes, no errors.

Comment: You have a colorbox, something that looks like log-data, the `biblatex` tag. I mean, please [provide a minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: @Johannes_B, this is minimal example. I just want to output some `linux` `dmesg` data in latex with grey background. Was the upper idea right way?

Comment: But Johannes means why did you tag the question biblatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I think a made a mistake

Comment: When we ask for a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we ask for a piece of code that we can just copy and paste from the question and immediately compile on our machines and reproduce the issue. Such a MWE (almost always) contains a `\documentclass` statement and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. What you posted can only be used to reproduce your problem if one is good at guessing certain things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the sledge hammer `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,colback=gray]
[862401.693536] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off\newline
[862401.693548] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08\newline
[862401.700884]  sdb: sdb1\newline
[862401.705538] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present\newline
[862401.705551] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through\newline
[862401.705562] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

`\colorbox` is like `\mbox` and in such a box glue is set to its natural size, which is `0pt` in the case of `\hfill` and `\break` sets a penalty for use in line breaking but no linebreaking happens in a horizontal box, so the penalty has no effect. If you want a paragraph inside an hbox you need

```
  \mbox{\parbox{5cm}{some text here}}
```

or the same with `\mbox` replaced by `\colorbox{yellow}`

`\hfill\break` should never be used in a latex document anyway, if you must force a break the latex syntax would be `\\` but that similarly needs to be in a `\parbox` not an `\mbox`.

Comment: Hmm. This requires knowing the width of the box beforehand, though... doesn't that negate the purpose of the hfill? Or is there a simple way to make that parbox streatch to the end of the line?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to do some highlighting with the `soul` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\sethlcolor{gray}\hl{[862401.693536] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off\\
[862401.693548] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08\\
[862401.700884]  sdb: sdb1\\
[862401.705538] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present\\
[862401.705551] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through\\
[862401.705562] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is much better, but I want to gray section to be on whole line of text, i.e. rectangular.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih in that case you want colorbox around a parbox, as in my answer:-)